# Consider the ring $( R = \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z} = \{[0]_{12}, [1]_{12}, ..., [11]_{12}\})$, and let ( I ) be its ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have solved a ring theory question but I am not sure whether my solution is correct. Can anyone Guide if there is mistake in it?

#### Question

Consider the ring $( R = \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z} = \{[0]_{12}, [1]_{12}, ..., [11]_{12}\})$, and let ( I ) be its ideal $( I = \{[0]_{12}, [3]_{12}, [6]_{12}, [9]_{12}\} ).$

(a) List explicitly all the cosets of $( I )$ in $( R ).$

(b) Write down the addition and multiplication tables for ( R/I ).

(c) Prove that $( R/I \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} )$, by giving an explicit isomorphism (there is no need to prove formally that it is an isomorphism).

#### Solution

##### Part (a)

\begin{align*}
0 + I &= \{0, 3, 6, 9\} \\
1 + I &= \{1, 4, 7, 10\} \\
2 + I &= \{2, 5, 8, 11\} \\
\end{align*}

##### Part (b)

Addition Table for $( R/I )$:

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
+ & [0] & [1] & [2] \\
\hline
[0] & [0] & [1] & [2] \\
[1] & [1] & [2] & [0] \\
[2] & [2] & [0] & [1] \\
\end{array}

Multiplication Table for ( R/I ):

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\times & [0] & [1] & [2] \\
\hline
[0] & [0] & [0] & [0] \\
[1] & [0] & [1] & [2] \\
[2] & [0] & [2] & [1] \\
\end{array}

##### Part (c)

Define the map $( \phi: R/I \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ by $( \phi([a]_{12}) = [a]_3)$.

\begin{align*}
\phi([a]_{12} + [b]_{12}) &= \phi([a+b]_{12}) = [a+b]_3 = [a]_3 + [b]_3 = \phi([a]_{12}) + \phi([b]_{12}) \\
\phi([a]_{12} \times [b]_{12}) &= \phi([a \times b]_{12}) = [a \times b]_3 = [a]_3 \times [b]_3 = \phi([a]_{12}) \times \phi([b]_{12}) \\
\end{align*}

$(\phi)$ is surjective and injective. Therefore, $( R/I \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Your map is incorrect. Elements of $R/I$ are cosets, not equivalence classes.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi:R/I\to \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ defined by$$\phi(0+I)=0$$ $$\phi(1+I)=1$$ $$\phi(2+I)=2$$
According to your work in part b, it seems very likely that $\phi$ is an isomorphism of rings:$$ R/I \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} $$

That's all that's required in part c.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal $(I)$ is just $\Bbb Z_4.$  Recognizing that makes it easy to see that $\mathcal R/I\cong \Bbb Z_{12}/\Bbb Z_4\cong (\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z)/(\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z)\cong 4\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z\cong \Bbb Z_3.$

I imagine that from the point of view of modules,  each submodule of a cyclic module is cyclic etc.    Since rings are not usually called cyclic.   But I am out of my element.